# I get error when instantiate new game object in unity. Can anybody help me with this?

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I want to split Rock into small pieces when they collide with the platform.

First, I created new small rocks gameobjects, added them to the empty gameobject and then put them into prefab folder and named them remainsRock which will be the little pieces of the Rock after collision.

In inspector i added remainsRock to the GameObject remains.

Then i tried to instantiate this remains after destroying the stone, but got this error. Does somebody know what to do ?

Error:

> UnassignedReferenceException: The variable remains of explosionEffect has not been assigned.
>   You probably need to assign the remains variable of the explosionEffect script in the inspector.

my code:

`public GameObject remains;`

```
if (collisionInfo.gameObject.tag == "cliff")
        {
            Instantiate(remains);
            Destroy(gameObject);

        }
```

I also tried:

`GameObject remainsInstantiate = (GameObject)Instantiate(remains, transform.position, transform.rotation);`

and

`GameObject instantiateRemains = (GameObject)Instantiate(remains);`

But none of them works. I will be glad if someone can help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure it's because something is **null**. To be specific your gameObject should be assigned somewhere, and right now it doesn't look like this is happening.

It's been awhile since I worked in Unity but I am pretty sure this is the issue.

Make sure you assigned your gameobject in Unity as well, not just in the code.

For example

```
Rigidbody2D rdg2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
// For you
gameObject = remains;
```

The code might not be perfect, but hopefully it's enough to push you in the right direction. If not I would maybe watch YouTubers quill18creates he's really good with Unity far better than me.

Answer (score 0):

> The variable remains of explosionEffect has not been assigned.

Let me highlight the important bit.

> **remains** has not been assigned.

`remains` is null. You can't instantiate null. It doesn't exist.

You have this:

```
Instantiate(remains);
```

You can't, because `remains` is null. You need to assign a GameObject to it, probably in the Inspector.  None of the things you tried were an attempt to assign a value to `remains` but instead trying to instantiate the null value that `remains` contains (it does not contain anything).

Grabbing a random script I have to give you a picture (names aren't the same as your scripts):

[image: No object assigned]

You need to find your `explosionEffect` script component and put a prefab there so that the variable is not null.  Just as my script can't follow an object that doesn't exist, your's can't clone something that doesn't exist.